# error creating database using ansible on centos 7

Tags: mysql, configuration-management, mariadb, ansible

I am trying to install mysql AND setup database using ANSIBLE on CentOS7(i have no idea why every documention in the world now ONLY talks about Ubuntu and NO CentOS anymore...really SAD!)

here is my create_db.yml file

```
---
- name: Install Python MySQLdb
yum: name=MySQL-python state=latest

- name: Create the Drupal database
mysql_db: db={{ db_name }} state=present

- name: Create the Drupal user
mysql_user: >
name={{ db_user }}
password={{ db_password }}
priv={{ db_name }}.*:ALL
host=localhost
```

ALSO here is my setup.yml file

```
---

- name: Install MySQL server
yum: name=mariadb-server state=latest

- name: Install php apache modules
  yum: name=php-gd state=latest

- name: Install php apache modules
 yum: name=php-ldap state=latest

- name: Install php apache modules
 yum: name=php-odbc state=latest

- name: Install php apache modules
 yum: name=php-pear state=latest

- name: Install php apache modules
yum: name=php-xml state=latest

- name: Install php apache modules
yum: name=php-xmlrpc state=latest

- name: Install php apache modules
yum: name=php-mbstring state=latest

- name: Install php apache modules
yum: name=php-snmp state=latest

- name: Install php apache modules
yum: name=php-soap state=latest

- name: Install php apache modules
yum: name=curl state=latest

- name: Install php apache modules
yum: name=curl-devel state=latest

- name: Install MySQL module for PHP
yum: name=php-mysql state=latest
```

NOW when ansible is running to install it, here is the error i get

```
TASK: [mysql | Install MySQL server] ******************************************
ok: [ansiblev1]

TASK: [mysql | Install php apache modules] ************************************
ok: [ansiblev1]

TASK: [mysql | Install php apache modules] ************************************
changed: [ansiblev1]

TASK: [mysql | Install php apache modules] ************************************
changed: [ansiblev1]

TASK: [mysql | Install php apache modules] ************************************
changed: [ansiblev1]

TASK: [mysql | Install php apache modules] ************************************
ok: [ansiblev1]

TASK: [mysql | Install php apache modules] ************************************
changed: [ansiblev1]

TASK: [mysql | Install php apache modules] ************************************
changed: [ansiblev1]

TASK: [mysql | Install php apache modules] ************************************
changed: [ansiblev1]

TASK: [mysql | Install php apache modules] ************************************
changed: [ansiblev1]

TASK: [mysql | Install php apache modules] ************************************
ok: [ansiblev1]

TASK: [mysql | Install php apache modules] ************************************
changed: [ansiblev1]

TASK: [mysql | Install MySQL module for PHP] **********************************
changed: [ansiblev1]

TASK: [mysql | Install Python MySQLdb] ****************************************
changed: [ansiblev1]

TASK: [mysql | Create the Drupal database] ************************************
failed: [ansiblev1] => {"failed": true}
msg: unable to connect, check login_user and login_password are correct, or    alternatively check ~/.my.cnf contains credentials

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
       to retry, use: --limit @/home/bbusari/site.retry

ansiblev1                  : ok=18   changed=10   unreachable=0    failed=1
```

What do i do to resolve this?
Running CentOS 7 and ansible-1.8.2-1.el7.noarch

Thanks

Comment: MySQL / MariaDB is installed.  Is it running?

Comment: actually it wasn't it checked with `sudo systemctl status mariadb.service` anyways started it manually and then ran the command again and it worked!!! so how can i make sure mariadb starts from ansible? Thanks

Comment: I haven't used ansible before but [this page](http://docs.ansible.com/service_module.html) looks like a good place to start.

Comment: yeah should have known that...thanks alot..ansible is really really easy compared to puppet and chef..i started learning ansible yesterday and now i have a full automated drupal install with ansible on ubuntu 14.04 and centos7..really easy

Answer (score 1):

To answer you question about ensure MariaDB is started:

```
- name: Set MariaDB to start now and on boot
  service: name=mysql state=started enabled=yes
```